# Cannot reach website from outside of LAN

Tags: apache-2.2, port, port-forwarding, local-area-network, wide-area-network

I am at much of a loss here, guys. I am running an Apache HTTP webserver from my laptop and I am unable to reach it from outside the routers borders/LAN. I cannot seem to ping it outside LAN and when I attempt to visit the website or my external IP address it returns an HTTP Error 503 - Service unavailable. Everything works splendid inside the LAN on every device.

I am running Apache 2.2.25 using Windows and own a domain name. And I use a static IP, of course. The IP is 212.10.172.87, if that is necessary.

The following is what I've attempted: disabled Windows Firewall, configured port forwarding on my router, asked my ISP if port 80 was blocked, which it was not. Turned off anti virus or anything that could be creating a wall. And followed numerous of guides and threads on Google about the topic. None seems to work, my website remains isolated.

Is my router's firewall blocking of some kind ? Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: What do your log files on the router report? Check if the logs report anything being blocked that pertains to your web site and it's associated IP/ports.

Comment: @Enigman My router has a restricted firmware and I am unable to update the firmware due to the ISP "controlling" it, so by checking the routers administration site it doesn't seem like I have access to any logs, unfortunately.

Comment: I have to say this: ping is not a web site testing tool. It's a basic connectivity tool useful ONLY when you know the device you're pinging should respond. In your case, worrying about the ping failures is likely a red herring that will have you wasting time figuring out why instead of focusing on the core issue. There are a number of external reasons your server may not respond to your pings, such as your firewall, router, etc. Focus on the core problem, which is that you can't reach your web site.

Comment: I haven't any good suggestion - except to be thorough - and I don't care all that much one way or there the other (just mildly curious), but I'm giving your question an up-vote because I think it's terrible some people down-vote what they perceive as novice questions - frankly, you've got a lot more clue than some I've seen! Good luck...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wiki list of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), 503 stands for "The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance)."

Although, in my experience as a PHP programmer, I have seen this error numerous times, caused by the greatest variety of problems. Sometimes this error may have something to do with the Apache mod_security module, the httpd.conf file or even the .htaccess files of your page.

At this very moment, though, I cannot ping, or access your IP from a browser. I even tried to telnet you on port 80, but it never responds.
This may indicate a port-forwarding or Firewall problem as you suspected.
Can you try to open a non-standard port, like 1234 and forward that to your laptop? Then also set your Apache to listen on that port and try to access it like 212.10.172.87:1234

I hope this may help you find the problem.

Comment: (I apologise for the unappropriate question this seeming is, however I'll take the liberty to reply). @mavrosxristoforos, thank you for your reply and effort. A few hours ago, I configured the port-forwarding to open port 1234 and Apache as well - no luck, unfortunately. Now I cannot even access my website from inside LAN. I'm am certain, as many of you speak of, that this needs more throughout research to solve, which it seems I need to seek. Or just pay a hosting company... Thank you all for your replies.

Comment: Make sure that you are trying just an index.html page. You shouldn't be debugging network issues and code issues at the same time.